# Colorbox iframe contact form without reload

Tags: php, ajax, email

I'm using my contact form via colorbox iframe, everything is showing fine, but I want this to work inside colorbox iframe without page refreshing. I know I need AJAX, but can you give me AJAX code to get this work? Sending my mail without refresh.

```
<?php
if ($_POST["email"]<>'') {
    $person = 'example@mail.com';
    $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode("Message from ".$_POST["name"]."")."?=";
    $header = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
    $content .= "<h1>Mailer info</h1>";
    $content .= "<b>Name:</b> ".$_POST["name"]."<br />";
    $content .= "<b>E-mail:</b> ".$_POST["email"]."<br />";
    $content .= "<b>Phone:</b> ".$_POST["phone"]."<br /><br />";
    $content .= "<h1>Message</h1>";
    $content .= "<b>".nl2br($_POST["message"])."</b>";
    mail($person, $subject, $content, $header) or die ("Failed.");
}
?>
<div id="formWrapper">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div class="message">
        <p>Your message has been sent successfully. You can close this window.</p>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" id="form">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" pattern="[a-z\A-Z\ \ą\ć\ę\ł\ń\ó\ś\ż\ź\-\+]{1,50}" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" required />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input type="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9\-\+]{1,15}" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="message">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" required ></textarea>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like someone was nice enough to do this for you, but StackOverflow isn't really for "can you give me code" requests. Really, you should try yourself. If you still have trouble, show us what you've tried, and demonstrate that you've made an effort. You know you need ajax. Why not try out a tutorial or 2 on "submitting a form without reload using ajax" first, or try out Answers from similar questions here? Lots of good stuff here: https://www.google.com/search?q=submitting+a+form+without+reload+using+ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery (which you should be if you're using Colorbox,) the following code should work:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var params = $(this).serialize();
    $.post(document.URL, params, function () {
        $('.message').show();
    });
});
```